# MySQL skipping 2147483646 on int(11) auto increment column

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

Here is my code:

```
create table test3 (
    num int(11) not null auto_increment,
    primary key (num)
) auto_increment=2147483644;

insert into test3 values();
insert into test3 values();
insert into test3 values();
insert into test3 values(); //duplicate key error

select * from test3;
```

You will notice that 2147483644, 2147483645, and 2147483647 are used, but not 2147483646. I can manually set something to 2147483646, but I want to understand *why* this happens. My innodb autoinc lock mode is 1 (the default for my version).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Comment: Is this test derived from some real problem?  Or are you doing some kind of QA?

Comment: out of curiosity. i was testing overflow behavior and came across it.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has been reported as a bug before, here in 2015:

[Bug #75941 auto_increment value jumps from the max row value - 2 to max](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75941)

A comment in that bug report claims the bug had been reported years earlier (circa 2010-2011).

No fix yet. I just tested MySQL 8.0.11, and the behavior is still as you describe.

You should login to the MySQL bug site and click the "Affects Me" button if you want to increase the priority of the bug.

Regardless, you should not rely on values of an auto-increment key being consecutive. Their only requirement is to be unique.